# Adb does not list LG G3 phone after Lollipop update on OS X

Tags: adb, lg-g3

I know a few questions have been asked about this, but I have not found a solution (particularly for OS X).

I updated my LG G3 to Lollipop and now `adb devices` does not list the device.

USB debugging is enabled on the device. The device seems to be stuck in MTP. Furthermore, the device requests to install PC Programs, but nothing happens when I allow it.

The device hasn't asked me to authorize my Mac for USB debugging, and I cannot find a way to get this prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This was finally solved by enabling Safe Mode, and changing the USB connection type from MTP to PTP (which was actually successful this time).

When changing to PTP, I was prompted to trust my computer. I allowed the connection & then `adb devices` listed the device.

Special thanks to based EB.